# Click download button within accordion using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the data from this webpage:
https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#trends_weeklydeaths_select_00

It is my first time using selenium, and I can't find the button to expand the first accordion (while I found the one to expand the second one).

For now, I have:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#trends_weeklydeaths_select_00')
button = driver.find_element(By.ID,"WHAT-IS-THE-ID")
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the selenium is not able to interact with these web elements, when you cannot use selenium's `click()` or `ActionChains` to interact with the element, you can use [JavaScript](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html).

Refer the working code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#trends_weeklydeaths_select_00")
driver.maximize_window()
# Below line creates WebDriverWait object which waits for 10s based on condition
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# Below 2 lines will click on first accordion element using JavaScript
accordion_btn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "us-trends-table-toggle")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", accordion_btn)
# Below 2 lines will click on download button using JavaScript
download_btn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "btnUSTrendsTableExport")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download_btn)
```